# Fill HTML canvas excluding arbitrary (possibly overlapping) circles

Tags: html, canvas

Given an HTML canvas that has already been drawn to, what's the best way to shade the whole canvas except given circular regions? (in context: shadows except where are there light sources)

I was hoping it would be as simple as a `rect()` followed by subsequent `arc()`s, but AFAIK there's no way to "remove" those circular sections after the fact. I can get close ( http://jsfiddle.net/mW8D3/2/), but the overlapping regions of circles end up shaded (in XOR fashion, whereas I want OR). Using `clip()` has the same problem.

I've also tried using `globalCompositeOperation` but can't quite seem to achieve what I want.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first create the shadow image on a second canvas and knock out holes from it with globalCompositeOperation 'copy' and a transparent fillStyle.

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/mW8D3/4/

Comment: I was hoping to avoid introducing another canvas, but glad to know this is an option. It appears that 'destination-atop' works as well.